Why is my React component not re-rendering after a state update?
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Counter = () => {
  // State to hold the counter value
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  // Function to handle the button click and update the counter
  const incrementCounter = () => {
    counter += 1; // Incorrect: Directly modifying state instead of using setCounter
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: "20px" }}>
      <h1>Counter: {counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={incrementCounter} style={{ padding: "10px 20px", fontSize: "16px" }}>
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;

I'm building a React application where I have a button that updates a counter state. The useState hook is used to manage the state. The counter updates as expected in the console, but the UI doesn't reflect the new value. I've verified that the component isn't receiving stale props

Because you are not updating the state. There's even a comment saying it's wrong.

Because you update your state counter directly instead of using setter function setCounter. You should always use the setter function when performing state updates.
To fix this behaviour, adjust incrementCounter function to use the setter:
  const incrementCounter = () => {
    setCounter( counter + 1 );
  };

